# External Keyboard with Italian layout not working on MacOS

Tags: keyboard

I'm on Mojave and I'm trying to use an external usb keyboard w/ an Italian layout (dell kb216 wired, see the picture below).

[image: https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/MRQAAOSwj35dg00y/s-l1600.jpg]

My Mac already mounts an integrated Italian keyboard. However, when I plug it, some keys behave weirdly. For example, the key on the left of the "1" prints "<" instead of "\". How can I fix this? The keyboard preferences are already in Italian.

Comment: What does the key to the left of z print??

Comment: It sounds like your machine is not recognizing the correct keyboard "type" of your external, thinking it is ANSI instead of ISO.  See this page for some fixes   https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: Ok I’ll let you know asap. Thanks for now. :)

Comment: Hey @TomGewecke, thank you very much. It worked quite smoothly. I've still some problems (e.g., the `INS` key is not working, and the `.` in the numeric keypad on the right is printed as a `,`. Is there a way to have a full compatibility w/ this keyboard (see picture in the main post for the complete layout)

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question about the INS and decimal point issues, as they are not related to the "type".  I think the decimal point thing has been answered a few times before in this forum if you search.

Comment: Ok, I'll look here for those pieces of info and, eventually, I'll open up a separate question. Thanks once again